# How to get new TXT verification record from firebase

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I've try to connect custom domain to firebase but I accidentally delete the TXT record in my dns manager after verifying phase. How can I get new TXT record?

Comment: I think if you click on the on your connected domain, you can your  view TXT record.

Comment: Thanks for replying, its not showing the verification Jagurti, but i already have new owner verification on google search console. But i'm not sure if it was the same with firebase gave to me.

Comment: i have this problem too. I have waited 2 days and it wont give me another TXT records. @Frank van Puffelen